# Does too many partial make the program speed slow with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

Rails framework's partial feature is very useful for view. If use too many partial in a project, does it make the program load speed slow?

Comment: Why not write some code to test the performance?

Comment: http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/02/13/how-much-time-does-rendering-a-partial-really-take/

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't. In fact, utilizing subviews instead of having single giant views is the preferred way of doing things. If you use a Ruby IDE such as RubyMine it will actually complain if you *don't* use subviews when you have a single view that starts getting too large.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should. It could be seen from the logs below that rendering time of large amount of the same partials is vary:

I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.328508 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (13.9ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.338626 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (8.6ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.348418 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (8.4ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.361821 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (11.7ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.373611 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (10.5ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.386695 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (11.4ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.398740 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (10.3ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.411959 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (10.9ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.424705 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (10.5ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.437990 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (11.3ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.449926 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (9.5ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.459979 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (8.6ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.472241 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (10.7ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.482611 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (9.0ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.494238 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (10.5ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.519543 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (14.6ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.531808 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (11.1ms)
I, [2015-07-27T03:02:57.545017 #8369]  INFO -- :   Rendered properties/_property.html.erb (11.2ms)

In this particular log the timing distribution among the partials is not that large. However, there are cases where one partial loads 1ms and the next one is 10ms. It might be mostly due to SQLs delays in the partial, but in any case resource allocation during execution of partials will require some time, and it may become noticeable on large N.